# why is my angular custom datepicker directive is setting ngModel to undefined for datepickers in ng-repeat?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a basic datepicker directive which is meant to simply apply the bootstrap datepicker to any input elements with the 'datepicker' directive.

It is also meant to refresh / update the datepicker once it has been disabled and then enabled again.

This works in general but lately, for some reason if the datepicker is in an ng-repeat, it just sets a null value to the $modelValue which I assume is a result from applying the datepicker before ngModel has been populated?

I have tried putting a watch on ngModel but it is always undefined.

Below is the bare bones of my directive and it still overwrites $modelValue.

```
  .directive('datepicker', ['$log', function ($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                replace: '=replaceNullWith'
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
                el.datepicker({
                    format: {
                        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
                            var d = new Date(date);
                            var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                            return d.getDate() + '-' + months[d.getMonth()] + '-' + (d.getFullYear() % 1000);
                        },
                        toValue: function (date, format, language) {
                            return date;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // every time a datepicker state changes from disabled to enable we have to re-enabled the datepicker
                scope.$watch(attr.ngDisabled, function (n, o) {
                    el.datepicker('update');
                });
            }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

```
if (ngModel.$modelValue) {
                angular.element(el).datepicker({
                    format: {
                        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
                            var d = new Date(date);


    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                                return d.getDate() + '-' + months[d.getMonth()] + '-' + (d.getFullYear() % 1000);
                            },
                            toValue: function (date, format, language) {
                                return date;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

 scope.$watch(ngModel.$modelValue, function (n, o) {
                angular.element(el).datepicker('destroy');
                angular.element(el).datepicker({
                    format: {
                        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
                            var d = new Date(date);
                            var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                            return d.getDate() + '-' + months[d.getMonth()] + '-' + (d.getFullYear() % 1000);
                        },
                        toValue: function (date, format, language) {
                            return date;
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
```

So basically, checking if the $modelValue is truthy before applying the datepicker and watching the $modelValue and destroying it and adding a new one each time. Probably a horrible way to do this but my datepickers now work in all ng-repeats